# Somebody has posted a link to my profile in twitter. Could you tell me what he wants to say?

Tags: meaning

This guy posted a link to my profile on [Twitter](http://twitter.com/#!/BoltClock/status/23986746832195584), could you tell me what he wants to say?

[image]

Comment: why down vote my question? I really cannot sure what he want to say.

Comment: Don't know why it got downvoted. +1.

Comment: According to META, the original "wanna" instead of want to in the title may have annoyed some purists.

Comment: @mplungjan I, as a no native speaker, don't have much more feel in word. So if somebody tell me 'wanna' means 'want to' then I just accept it.

Comment: I understand. I just answered your question "why downvote my question" since I saw a discussion about silent editing on meta that mentioned your question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think BoltClock is pointing out that it's kind of a strange thing to say. For other readers, this is your profile text reposted:

> I'm an advanced typist. I can type in many languages, including Chinese, English, c++, php, javascript and SQL.

When you say "typist", it means the action of actually typing -- pushing the keys that make the words come out on the screen. The only way someone becomes an advanced typist is by being a faster typist. This is because the word "typist" used to [refer to a clerk or secretary who was paid to operate a mechanical typewriter](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=define%3atypist). For example, you don't be a typist by knowing C++, just as you don't know C++ by being a typist. Being a typist means you can type quickly, while knowing C++ means you can program in that language. (Granted, any good C++ programmer is also going to know how to type, but that doesn't mean you can't know the language and still be a hunt-and-peck person)\

What you probably want is "Advanced programmer", because ["programmer" specifically indicates](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=define%3aprogrammer&btnG=Search) a computer operator who knows one or more programming languages, which seems to be the message you want to convey with your list of languages.

Comment: And *I* think he was making a clever statement in his profile. Rather like [Steve Yegge's old post](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2008/09/programmings-dirtiest-little-secret.html).

Comment: @Billy Sorry for my poor English, But it's a joke (or I want to say a joke). I really know I'm a programmer.

Comment: @lovespring: Your English isn't bad. (The only reason I knew you weren't a native speaker is because it says so in your profile :P) I just didn't see the joke, and I could see how others might not get the joke. (But once you tell them why the joke is funny they feel like an idiot, as I do now :( )

Comment: "I am a keyboard monkey" may have been clearer ;)

Comment: I see. thank you! I just translate the profile joke words by words from my profile in my native language.

Comment: @lovespring: One more thought -- one of the reasons I didn't look for double meanings in what was posted was probably simply that English is listed as a nonnative language in your profile. This is a special case of the " [sometimes it's easier to just let the native speaker win](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/06/13/8593846.aspx) " stigma that follows non-native-speakers around. (Sorry for being a bit of a jerk lol :) )

Answer (score 3):

Your [Stack Overflow profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/84325/lovespring) currently says:

> I'm an advanced typist. I can type in many languages, including Chinese, English, c++, php, javascript and SQL.

Your [Stack Overflow profile](http://web.archive.org/web/20100813073012/https://stackoverflow.com/users/84325/lovespring) used to say:

> I'm a advanced typist. I can type in many language, including Chinese, English, c++, php, javascript and SQL.

He's pointing out that an advanced typist should know how to type, spell and capitalise properly. It should really be:

> I'm an advanced typist. I can type in many languages, including Chinese, English, C++, PHP, JavaScript and SQL.

In fact, it's usual only to mention your *typing skills* in natural languages, and only if you really mean the physical skill of typing at a keyboard. It might be that you want to say your an advanced speaker of these languages. And for programming languages, you'd more likely talk about your *programming skills*.

Answer (score 2):

"A advanced typist" is bad English, which he assumed to be bad typing, and so funny where you claim to be a good typist. (Your joke is not relevant to his joke).